# How effective are welding blankets?

Tags: welding

I am a novice welder (D.I.Y).

I need to weld in a very sensitive area. It will be surrounded by PVC and other plastics withing about 30-50cm of where I have to weld.

I have an inverter arc welder, and I am worried about spatter etc when welding in this sensitive area. I can have absolutely no welding spatter touch the PVC and other plastic areas as they will undoubtedly destroy whatever they land on.

I am thinking about using a welding blanket(s) to pad the area. I have no experience with using welding blankets, and I am a bit nervous. If something does get through, it will be quite an issue.

My other idea is to build a metal "funnel" if you will, to enclose the area, and then weld inside the "funnel". The weld should be a quick weld, but I may have to do it in multiple locations for the foreseeable future every time something breaks.

If you are really curious about the scenario... I have a trampoline park, and from time to time I have to remove some of the starts where the trampolines are strung from, to make repairs. The struts (locked with big grub screws), work their way loose and fatigues the metal to the point of breaking the head of the strut where it slots into the main pillar.

This normally happens at an awkward time, and I have to fix it early before opening the next day. I have to completely remove the strut, rebuild the head (L-shape), and reinstall and re-hook all the springs.

This is a re-occurring problem, and I want to create a permanent fix. I want to weld the strut beams to the center pillars. This will not carry any weight, but just stop it from moving side to side and fatiguing the metal. I will be a quick weld. I am not worried about heat transfer, just spatter.

I cant unhook all the trampolines and padding every time this happens, as it takes quite a while to re-hook and reassembles (4) trampolines encompassing where the break is.

My idea is to unhook just a few springs in order to be able to work, and then cover that surrounding area, padding, and trampoline mats, with welding blankets... Do the weld, and get on with my day.

Ideally I would have unhooked ALL the trampolines and padding, make all the welds, and re-assemble. To do this I would have to probably close the business for a few days, which I really cant afford.

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1):

If you get the proper quality welding blankets then  the protection they offer is superb. Just make sure there are no gaps.

If you use other coverings make sure they are not flammable - finding out you have flames running up behind you is no fun :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have indeed set my table alight and only saw it after doing a long weld coming back up for air. It's quite a site to be confronted with a table on fire... ;-)